# Android BroadcastReceiver помогите

Tags: java, android

У меня есть класс унаследованный от BroadcastReceiver, в нем создаются напоминания, так же у меня есть активити которое создает и сохраняет список времени от и до в виде строки, как мне сделать так что бы напоминания не срабатывали(откладывались) в эти промежутки времени? Проблема в том, что бы передать эту строку в класс BroadcastReceiver, т.к. приложение не активно, то надо загрузить эту сроку не из активности. Для сохранения использую SharedPreferences. Может использовать сериаллизацию? Но тогда куда сохранять фаил? и такое решение мне не очень нравится. В классе  BroadcastReceiver пока не писал реализацию обработки нужной строки.

```
    public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.u)
            // большая картинка
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.w))
            //.setTicker(res.getString(R.string.warning)) // текст в строке состояния
            .setTicker("Последнее китайское предупреждение!")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            //.setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notifytitle)) // Заголовок уведомления
            .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
            //.setContentText(res.getString(R.string.notifytext))
            .setContentText("У вас есть колоды требующие повторения."); // Текст уведомления

    // Notification notification = builder.getNotification(); // до API 16
    Notification notification = builder.build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);


    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, Alarm.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

}

public void ssetAlarm(Context context, Date ddr, Date dateBl) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(ddr.getTime());
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    intent.putExtra(String.valueOf(dateBl.getTime()), String.valueOf(dateBl.getTime()));//Задаем параметр интента
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) dateBl.getTime(), intent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
}


public void cancelAlarm(Context context,Date ddr) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) 
        ddr.getTime(), intent, 0);
        //            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        sender.cancel();
         //        if (alarmManager != null) {
        //            alarmManager.cancel(sender);
          //        }
          }
         }
```

И подскажи те заодно пожалуйста правильно ли реализован сам механизм этого класса? меня смущает эта часть, может она должна быть в другом месте программы?

```
     ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, Alarm.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: И правильно смущает - бессмысленно включать ресивер, когда он уже выполняется . И применительно к этому классу данный код вообще не нужен.

Comment: А куда надо пихать этот ресивер?

Comment: В, смысле, "пихать"? Я имел ввиду код в конце вопроса - он здесь лишний, остальное как бы верно.

Comment: Я так понимаю что этот ресивер нужен для того, что бы после рестарта устройства аларм менеджер все равно срабатывал по расписанию, но где должен распологаться этот кусок кода? В майнактивити он выдает ошибку)

Comment: Нет - Ваш ресивер исключительно выводит уведомление, и всё. Для восстановления расписания после перезагрузки нужен ресивер на action `BOOT_COMPLETED`: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot . И в нём установить все алармы заново. Естественно для этого надо их все при создании "запоминать" в `SharedPreferences`, файл, или базу - как Вам удобней.

Comment: Я так и не понял как обратиться к SharedPreferences из класса не унаследованного от активности. И я правильно понял то этот спорный кусок кода надо использовать в месте где происходит установка будильника?

Comment: В `onReceive()` приходит `context` через него и обращайтесь `context.getSharedPreferences(...)`. Да, спорный кусок должен включать Ваш BootReceiver при установке будильника и выключать когда все будильники отменены или закончились.